# Sql Relative DB username

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have two tables:

user [id, username]

comment [title, content, postid, userid]

my backend is nodejs...
how can i query all comments and not get the id, but the username in the result?

```
Select * from comments where postid=1
```

In this case, i'll get the userid in the result
Do i need a relative db?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hint: Or `IN()`

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
select username,title,content from user  u join comments c on u.id=c.userid
```